# Client certificate is not being sent to the server

Tags: ssl-certificate, soapui, wireshark, soap-client, client-certificates

There is one soap web service its working with 2 way SSL. Our client certificate(public key) has been shared with web service provider.

We are trying to call this soap web service on a latest SOAPUI 5.5 on Windows 2012 R2 machine.

We have configured our certificate (private key) in soapui and we are capturing the logs with wireshark during execution.

Wireshark says client certificate is not being sent as you can see on below screenshot. I can give more details if required...

[image]

You can see also SOAPUI configuration and service call on below...

Client Certificate Configuration in SOAPUI:
[image]

Service call execution in SOAPUI:
[image]

**Edit 1:** We have spent 8 days to figure out this problem. If anyone believes to solve this problem for us, we are ok to pay for it. Thank you.

Comment: Is this programming related? If not, post it on https://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but actually, its most related with 2 way ssl and soap 
 web services..There is no connectivity issue.

Comment: I'm affraid I cannot see any relationship with SO, you have to ask it on other communities like Andreas said if you really want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Configure the key store along with the request testStep .

1. select the request test step
2. go to properties and select keystore which you want to send

I hope the key store you are using have the server certificate imported.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. **Key Password mismatch**: Assuming that your keystore password is correct, it could be happening due to mismatch between the *keystore
   password* and the *key password*. This could often happen if the
   password of the keystore is changed and forgot to update the
   password of the underlying key. In this case the SoapUI accepts the
   keystore because the password is correct. But while sending the
   request, the SoapUI also requires the password of the underlying
   private key in the keystore. Due to mismatch of the passwords, the
   SoapUI is not able to decrypt the key and send it along with the
   request.
2. **Set SSL Keystore request Param**: There is a request param called SSL Keystore. Select the keystore from the dropdown before sending
   the request. If you do not see the keystore in the dropdown, add the
   keystore like below: Double Click on the SOAP Project --> Goto WS
   Security Configurations --> Keystores --> Click on (+) to add your
   keystore --> select keystore from your filepath --> Give keystore
   password --> The keystore should add with status OK.  Now select
   this keystore in your *SSl Keystore* request parameter. And send the
   request.